# How do I prevent C# HttpClient from converting %2D to dash in querystring when GET request is executed?

Tags: c#, httpclient

C#, Framework 4.5

RestSharp 105.2.3 (version works on framework 4.5)

I am sending a GET request to an api, with a querystring that has hex value %2D for dashes. The api will not accept dashes, it must be formatted with %2D. Both the Uri create and the GET request through either the C# HttpClient or RestSharp converts the %2D into a dash when the request is executed. Does anyone know of a setting or property that will prevent the request from converting to a dash?

```
//this is a mock of the initial value
var httpUrl = "https://theapiendpointwithhex.com/api/order?orderid=bee3d72e%2D8170%2D4bad%2Dba95632b09de42ad"

//creating a new Uri
Uri rsUri = new Uri(httpUrl);

//if you view the querytring, it has converted the 2D to dash:
string httpUrlQuery = rsUri.Query;
//httpUrlQuery is ?orderid=bee3d72e-8170-4bad-ba95632b09de42ad
```

Even if I correct it or use the original in the httpClient request, it converts it to dashes.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://theapiendpointwithhex.com");

var result = client.GetAsync("/api/order?orderid=bee3d72e%2D8170%2D4bad%2Dba95632b09de42ad").Result;
var testContent = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

the raw request I can see in fiddler is

GET https://theapiendpointwithhex.com/api/order?orderid=bee3d72e-8170-4bad-ba95632b09de42ad

If I change the dashes to %2D in fiddler and re-issue the request, it returns success

The same thing happens if I try another library such as RestSharp
AND it happens if I add the querystring as a parameter in restsharp such as

```
RestClient rsClient = new RestClient(hostAndPath);
RestRequest rsRequest = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
rsRequest.AddQueryParameter("orderid","bee3d72e%2D8170%2D4bad%2Dba95632b09de42ad"); //converts this to dashes in request
var restResponse = rsClient.Execute(rsRequest);
```

Comment: `-` is not a reserved URL character, so you could argue that this is a bug in the server.